# How do I get a single URL removed from Google Search results?

Tags: google-search

I keep running into URLs that no longer exist, but which Google Search still returns and end up giving me a 404 error. I know it'll get re-scanned eventually, but how do I prompt Google to re-scan it sooner?

Answer (score 1):

You can request removal of a single search result by using the "[**Remove outdated content**](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1)" tool.

They note:

> Instructions:
>
> - This request works only for pages/images that have **already been modified, or removed from the web**.
> - If you need to remove **personal information or content with legal issues**, you should submit [this request instead](https://support.google.com/legal).
> - Enter the URL **copied from [Google Search Results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/63758)**.
> - **If successful**, cached result and snippet will be removed from Google Search results.
> - **If unsuccessful**, [learn why](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/63756).

They don't mention how long it will take, but it certainly should be shorter than waiting for Googlebot to come around again.

More details about the [Remove outdated content tool from Google Support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154).